# Multiple class diagram Java Android

Tags: java, android, class-diagram

I want to write an app for workouts and I need to some advice for the class diagram. I want the user to be able to use the app at the gym. The user will start a workout, do an arbitrary number of exercises, each with an arbitrary number of sets.

The way I thought of it is like this:

-Each workout has a date and a time. This enables them to be unique even if the user works out more than once a day.

-Each exercise has a name.

-Each set has a weight and a rep count.

Example:

20xx-XX-XX XX:XX (workout)
Squats (exercise)
100x5 (set)
100x5 (set)
100x5 (set)
Bench press (exercise)
50x8 (set)
50x8 (set)
50x8 (set)

So, what is the best way to put all this together? I thought maybe each workout could have a map with exercises as keys and arraylists containing sets as values. Is this a good solution? Or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User 
{
   List<Workout> _workouts;
}

class Workout
{
    Date _startdate;
    Date _enddate;
    Map<Exercise,List<Set>> _exercises;
}

class Exercise
{
    String _name;
}        

abstract class Set
{
    abstract int getTotal();
}

class WeightSet extends Set
{
    int _weight;
    int _reps;

    @override
    public String toString() {return _weight + "X" + _reps;}
}

class CardioSet extends Set
{
    int _durationInSeconds; 
    int _distance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the user, thats a good thing to put in. But does this not mean that the same exercise will get different instances depending on the list of sets it has in its list?

Comment: Yeah, in this case, it's specific to a workout session. If you wanted exercise more static, then you're suggestion of a Map might be better. I will edit my example

Comment: Cheers mate! You have confirmed that the design is indeed not too shabby at all and given me some nice extra things to add.